# Adding quotes to a CSV using perl

Tags: regex, perl, replace

I've got a CSV that looks as follows:

```
A,01,ALPHA
00,D,CHARLIE
E,F,02
```

This is the desired file after transformation:

```
"A",01,"ALPHA"
00,"D","CHARLIE"
"E","F",02
```

As you can see, the fields that are entirely numeric are left unquoted, whilst the alpha (or alphanumeric ones) are quoted.

What would be a sensible way to go about this in Perl ?

Already commented below, but I've tried stuff like

```
perl -pe 's/(\w+)/"$1"/g'
```

And that doesn't work because \w obviously picks up the numerics.

Comment: What have you tried? What difficulties are you having? Could you show us the code you've written so far to solve this?

Comment: Well, for example, stuff like perl -pe 's/(\w+)/"$1"/g' ... it doesn't work because \w also picks up the numerics.

Comment: That's a start at least. I think using a csv parser would be the best approach. But I'm not familiar with them, so for a quick fix, I can suggest something like `perl -pe 's%[^,\n]+%$&=~/^\d+$/?$&:qq{"$&"}%ge'`.

Comment: @PerlDuck I tried \D but that didn't have the desired effect for me unfortunatley.

Comment: @Dada I think I'll simply refer to you as the big daddy of Regex.   That's one spectacular one-liner !  As for CSV parsers, you're probably right, although to be honest I didn't even know there was such a thing until you metioned it !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend not reinventing the wheel, but rather to use an already existing module, as zdim recommends.  Here is your example using [Text::CSV_XS](http://search.cpan.org/~hmbrand/Text-CSV_XS-1.25/CSV_XS.pm)

**test.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use Text::CSV_XS;
use Scalar::Util qw( looks_like_number );

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new();
while (my $row = $csv->getline(*STDIN)) {
    my @quoted_row = map { looks_like_number($_) ? $_ : '"'. $_ .'"' } @$row;
    print join(',',@quoted_row) . "\n";
}
```

**Output**

```
cat input | perl test.pl
"A",01,"ALPHA"
00,"D","CHARLIE"
"E","F",02
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are after a one-liner. Here is a basic one

```
perl -lpe '$_ = join ",", map /^\d+$/ ? $_ : "\"$_\"", split ",";' input.csv
```

Splits each line by `,` and passes obtained list to `map`. There each element is tested for digits-only `/^\d+$/` and passed untouched, or padded with `"` otherwise.  Then `map`'s return is joined by `,`.

The `-l` removes newline, what is needed since `"` pad the whole line. The result is assigned back to `$_` in order to be able to use `-p` so that there is no need for explicit print.

The code is very easily used in a script, if you don't insist on an one-liner.

Processing of csv files is far better done by modules, for example [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.33/lib/Text/CSV.pm)

Comment: why not use `-F,` to get the split into `@F` array?

Comment: @Sundeep  Sure, possible.  Along with a whole host of other good tricks -- this was meant to be very basic, just like a normal easy script would do.

Answer (score 1):

Another one-liner, input file modified to add a line with alphanumeric fields

```
$ cat ip.csv 
A,01,ALPHA
00,D,CHARLIE
E,F,02
23,AB12,53C

$ perl -F, -lane 's/.*[^0-9].*/"$&"/ foreach(@F); print join ",", @F' ip.csv 
"A",01,"ALPHA"
00,"D","CHARLIE"
"E","F",02
23,"AB12","53C"
```

To modify OP's attempt:

```
$ perl -pe 's/(^|,)\K\d+(?=,|$)(*SKIP)(*F)|\w+/"$&"/g' ip.csv 
"A",01,"ALPHA"
00,"D","CHARLIE"
"E","F",02
23,"AB12","53C"
```

- `(^|,)\K\d+(?=,|$)(*SKIP)(*F)` this will skip the fields with digits alone and the alternate pattern `\w+` will get replaced